# How to stop/start rails/webrick when using JRuby with nailgun?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby, nailgun

This is probably a stupid question, but not having much joy researching it myself.

Using JRuby 1.6.4 on OSX (Snow Leopard) installed via rvm.

I have [enabled nailgun](http://samuel.kadolph.com/2011/08/speeding-up-jruby-with-nailgun/) .

Can start rails/webrick (rails s) and things seem fine.

Now I want to stop/start rails - how do I do that?

I did the usual Control-C, which looks to kill the rails command - however, as its really running on the background nailgun daemon, its not killed.

If I restart rails now, I get an error about port 3000 in use - its trying to start a second webrick.

If I kill the background daemon (using kill), JRuby then fails to start (connection refused).  Starting a new terminal window seems to fix this.

This doesnt seem like the right way to be doing this, but what is?

I have looked at [Headius' guide](http://blog.headius.com/2009/05/jruby-nailgun-support-in-130.html) and the [Nailgun project page](http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/) - but neither go that far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a known problem.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-3983?focusedCommentId=192413&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-192413

Comment: It does indeed - phew, thought I was missing something obvious :)